# Toggling logic for when 1 drawer is open

Tags: jquery, toggle

I currently have a working drawer where when the button is clicked and the drawer opens it toggles from a `+` pseudo to a `-`.

However if both of the drawers are opened consecutively the jQuery doesn't understand that the first drawer is now closed (because the second has been opened). I have added the jQuery script below:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".nav-acdn-container .mob-nav-btn").click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('plus-sign minus-sign');
    $(this).next().toggle();

    if ($('.nav-acdn-container ul:visible').length > 1) {
      $('.nav-acdn-container ul:visible').hide();
      $(this).next().show();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-content-m header-btn-hidden" data-panel="nav-btn-m">
  <div class="nav-acdn-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-acdn-container">
      <div class="mob-nav-btn plus-sign">Products</div>
      <ul class="ul-reset">
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="27d-gel-polish-4-c.asp">27D Gel Polish</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="accessories-11-c.asp">Accessories</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="acrylic-powder-collections-7-c.asp">Acrylic Powder Collections</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="acrylic-products-2-c.asp">Acrylic Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="brushes--cases-6-c.asp">Brushes & Cases</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="files-forms-tips-10-c.asp">Files, Forms, Tips</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="gel-products-3-c.asp">Gel Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="glamour-collection-12-c.asp">Glamour Collection</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="nail-art-8-c.asp">Nail Art</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="nail-wraps-5-c.asp">Nail Wraps</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="network-gel-21-c.asp">Network Gel</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="no1-wipe-gel-17-c.asp">No.1 Wipe Gel</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="orgasmic-paints-9-c.asp">Orgasmic Paints</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="pop-art-gel-16-c.asp">Pop Art Gel</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="soak-off-polygel-18-c.asp">Soak Off PolyGEL</a></li>

      </ul>
      <!-- /.ul-reset -->
    </div>
    <!--/.nav-acdn-container-->

    <div class="nav-acdn-container">
      <div class="mob-nav-btn plus-sign">Webpages</div>

      <ul class="ul-reset">
        <li class="nav-acdn-item">
          <a href="index.asp">Home</a>
        </li>
        <!-- /.flex-col .d-col-6 .webpages-item -->

        <li class="nav-acdn-item">
          <a href="about-us-1-w.asp">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <!-- /.flex-col .d-col-6 .webpages-item -->

        <li class="nav-acdn-item">
          <a href="about-me-4-w.asp">About Me</a>
        </li>
        <!-- /.flex-col .d-col-6 .webpages-item -->

        <li class="nav-acdn-item">
          <a href="courses-3-w.asp">Courses</a>
        </li>
        <!-- /.flex-col .d-col-6 .webpages-item -->

        <li class="nav-acdn-item">
          <a href="course-dates-21-w.asp">Course Dates</a>
        </li>
        <!-- /.flex-col .d-col-6 .webpages-item -->

        <li class="nav-acdn-item">
          <a href="contact-us-2-w.asp">Contact Us</a>
        </li>
        <!-- /.flex-col .d-col-6 .webpages-item -->

    </div>
    <!--/.nav-acdn-container-->
  </div>
  <!-- /.nav-acdn-wrapper -->
</nav>
<!-- /.nav-content-m .header-btn-hidden -->
```

```
<style>
.minus-sign:after {
    content: "\f068";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding-right: 1.2rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}

.plus-sign:after {
    content: "\f067";
    font-family: FontAwesome;
    font-size: 1.2rem;
    padding-right: 1.2rem;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Could you please add the relevant HTML to the question. It's easier to diagnose issues like this when you can see a working example of the problem

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan do you need the style too?

Comment: Seems like odd logic - you toggle the ul, then you check to see if it is visible and hide it instead of hiding and showing again, why not add a `not($(this).next())`

Comment: @Kaddath I pulled this jquery from a codepen, so is the length not neccesary for 2? Sorry I am really new to js

Comment: it seems to work when i try in a snippet..

Comment: This appears to work. What's the behaviour you're trying to create (or prevent)?

Comment: Everything works when I open products and then close products (the + and - are perfect) however if I then open products and then webpages straight after they both have the same psuedo when the original one (products) should go back to the + if that makes any sense

Comment: Ah right, now I understand the issue. I added an answer for you below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because your logic detects if one of the sub menus is open and then closes both, but only resets the CSS styles on the current one.

To fix this, and improve the logic, you could toggle a class on the `.nav-acdn-container` element and hook all the relevant CSS off that, something like this:

```js
$(".nav-acdn-container .mob-nav-btn").click(function() {
  var $target = $(this).closest('.nav-acdn-container').toggleClass('open');
  $('.nav-acdn-container').not($target).removeClass('open');
});
```

```css
.nav-acdn-container .mob-nav-btn:after {
  content: '+';
}
.nav-acdn-container ul {
  display: none;
}

.nav-acdn-container.open .mob-nav-btn:after {
  content: '-';
}
.nav-acdn-container.open ul {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav-content-m header-btn-hidden" data-panel="nav-btn-m">
  <div class="nav-acdn-wrapper">
    <div class="nav-acdn-container open">
      <div class="mob-nav-btn">Products</div>
      <ul class="ul-reset">
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="27d-gel-polish-4-c.asp">27D Gel Polish</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="accessories-11-c.asp">Accessories</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="acrylic-powder-collections-7-c.asp">Acrylic Powder Collections</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="acrylic-products-2-c.asp">Acrylic Products</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="brushes--cases-6-c.asp">Brushes &amp; Cases</a></li>       
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="nav-acdn-container">
      <div class="mob-nav-btn">Webpages</div>
      <ul class="ul-reset">
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="index.asp">Home</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="about-us-1-w.asp">About Us</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="about-me-4-w.asp">About Me</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="courses-3-w.asp">Courses</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="course-dates-21-w.asp">Course Dates</a></li>
        <li class="nav-acdn-item"><a href="contact-us-2-w.asp">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Note that I removed some of the `li` elements in the example to make it shorter, and also included the `</ul>` tag that was missing near the end.